# mypy and django: error: Library stubs not installed for "six" (or incompatible with Python 3.9)

Tags: django, mypy

I have setup mypy for a django project

```
[mypy]
# The mypy configurations: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html
python_version = 3.9

check_untyped_defs = True
# disallow_any_explicit = True
disallow_any_generics = True
disallow_untyped_calls = True
disallow_untyped_decorators = True
ignore_errors = False
ignore_missing_imports = True
implicit_reexport = False
strict_optional = True
strict_equality = True
no_implicit_optional = True
warn_unused_ignores = True
warn_redundant_casts = True
warn_unused_configs = True
warn_unreachable = True
warn_no_return = True
mypy_path = /home/user/app/backend_django/src

plugins =
  mypy_django_plugin.main,
  mypy_drf_plugin.main

[mypy.plugins.django-stubs]
django_settings_module = project.settings
```

Now I get

```
settings.py:21: error: Library stubs not installed for "six" (or incompatible with Python 3.9)
```

In `settings.py` I am importing `six`

So how to get this error resolved.

I have `django-stubs` installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try running mypy after adding `types-six` to your environment:

`pip install types-six`

see [the note in the mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#library-stubs-and-typeshed). the behavior of stubs has changed starting from mypy>=0.9.

Comment: but six is working fine without installing `pip install types-six`. I only installed django. Why to again install

Comment: types-six is only needed to fix the mypy error when type checking. your code will run without types-six. does that make sense? the example in the link to the docs could help clarify.

Comment: @lunguini could you explain if there is a reason behind this? to me it seems ridiculous to install a package just to silent a linter. perhaps I am missing something. thank you!